# Tkinter close protocol when tkinter is threaded

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have this small code that execute a function and in the meanwhile shows an indeterminate tkinter progressbar. When you let the program execute everything works fine while if you try to stop the process by closing the tkinter window you get the RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop. I understand that the solution could be to bring the bar mainloop in the main thread or alternatively use queue but it is not clear to me how to do this. Here you can find the code with a simple mock function (addit) that executes. Thank you everyone in advance!

```
import threading
importing tkinter module
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import Label
import sys
import time



class tkwindow(threading.Thread):


    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, daemon=True)

        
        
    def run(self):
        self.wbar=tkinter.Tk()
        self.wbar.attributes("-topmost", True) 
        self.wbar.title('Tool')
        lb=Label(self.wbar,text='Check in progress')
        lb.pack()
        pbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.wbar,orient='horizontal', length=500, mode='indeterminate')
        pbar.pack(pady=25)
        pbar.start(50) 
        self.wbar.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
        self.loopmain()
        
    def loopmain(self):
        
        self.wbar.mainloop()
        
               
        
    def quitall(self):
        
        self.wbar.quit()
        sys.exit()
      
    def on_closing(self):
        if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
          self.wbar.quit()
          sys.exit()   
        
       

def main(): 

    mygui=tkwindow()     
    mygui.start()
    addit(2,3)
    
    mygui.quitall()
         


def addit(a,b):
    time.sleep(3)
    print(a+b)
    return


if __name__=='__main__':  
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably I have found a way to do just what I wanted using queue. Unfortunately the code kill the main thread abruptly with interrupt_main and not in a nice way as sys.exit() could do but is the only solution I have found for now. The updated code is the following:

```
import threading
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import Label
import sys
import time
from queue import Queue
import _thread
import os



class tkwindow(threading.Thread):


    def __init__(self,dataq):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, daemon=True)
        self.dataq=dataq

        
        
    def run(self):
        self.wbar=tkinter.Tk()
        self.wbar.attributes("-topmost", True) 
        self.wbar.title('Tool')
        lb=Label(self.wbar,text='Check in progress')
        lb.pack()
        pbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.wbar,orient='horizontal', length=500, mode='indeterminate')
        pbar.pack(pady=25)
        pbar.start(50) 
        self.dataq.put(0)
        self.loopmain()
        
    def loopmain(self):
        self.wbar.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
        self.wbar.after(100,self.checkq)
        self.wbar.mainloop()
        
        
    def checkq(self):
        
        v=self.dataq.get()
        if v:
          if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
            self.wbar.quit()
            os._exit(0)  #or alternatively _thread.interrupt_main()
            
         
        
    def quitall(self):
        
        self.wbar.quit()
        sys.exit()

      
    def on_closing(self):
        self.dataq.put(1)
        self.checkq()




def main(): 
    dataq=Queue()
    mygui=tkwindow(dataq)     
    mygui.start()
    addit(2,3)   
    mygui.quitall()
    


def addit(a,b):

    time.sleep(3)
    print(a+b)
    return

    
   

if __name__=='__main__':  
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the code is only wrong. You should inherit `tk.Tk` and not `threading.Thread`. Instead of creating a function for the mainloop, just insert it at the bottom of the `run()` function (use `self` instead of `self.wbar`). Initialize the thread at the start of the `run()` function. In the  `main()` function you have called start but in the class you  defined it as `run()`. Here is your code if you added the above changes and fixed all errors:

```py
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import Label
import sys
import time

class tkwindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def run(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, daemon=True)
        self.attributes("-topmost", True) 
        self.title('Tool')
        lb=Label(self, text='Check in progress')
        lb.pack()
        pbar = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient='horizontal', length=500, mode='indeterminate')
        pbar.pack(pady=25)
        pbar.start(50) 
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
        self.mainloop()
    
    def quitall(self):
        self.quit()
        sys.exit()
      
    def on_closing(self):
        if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
          self.quitall()       

def main(): 
    mygui=tkwindow()     
    mygui.run()
    addit(2,3)
    
    mygui.quitall()

def addit(a,b):
    time.sleep(3)
    print(a+b)
    return

if __name__=='__main__':  
    main()
```

There is no way to put the progress bar into the thread. Even if you could, it wouldn't be of any use since it would make the code very complex. So just use this as an alternative.

## Updated Code

```py
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import Label
import sys
import time

class tkwindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def run(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, daemon=True)
        self.attributes("-topmost", True) 
        self.title('Tool')
        lb=Label(self, text='Check in progress')
        lb.pack()
        pbar = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient='horizontal', length=500, mode='indeterminate')
        pbar.pack(pady=25)
        pbar.start(50) 
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
    
    def quitall(self):
        self.quit()
        sys.exit()
      
    def on_closing(self):
        if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
          self.quitall() 

def main(): 
    mygui=tkwindow()     
    mygui.run()
    addit(2,3)
    
    mygui.mainloop()
    
def addit(a,b):
    print("ADDIT")
    threading.Timer(3, lambda: print(a+b)).start()
    
if __name__=='__main__':  
    main()
```

Comment: This is probably the only way to correct your error and there is likely no alternative. So if this is a part of a bigger program or a minimum reproducible example you would have to make many changes in your code to fix it. Hope it helped

Comment: I am sorry @pycoder, but your code doesn't seem to work as intended. It does not execute at all the addit function but it is stuck in the mainloop. In addition, when trying to close the tkinter window the SystemExit happens but the window just stay there but freezed.

Comment: Well for me the window did not freeze but it closed properly. Also now i noticed that it is not calling the addit function.

Comment: I just posted the updated code, Just replaced time.sleep() with threading.Timer() (time.sleep() stops the whole program for some time) and changed the position of the mainloop. Hope it works